# Notch Filter with given Bandwidth

Tags: matlab, filters, bandwidth

I have to use Matlab with the `iirnotch()`-function to design a notch filter. The notch should sit at 520Hz, the Bandwidth should be 100Hz and I have a sampling frequency of 8000Hz.

The syntax for `iirnotch()` is

```
iirnotch(w0, bw)
```

See [the example at the Mathworks-page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/iirnotch.html). After reading the doc, i now know how i should use the `w0`
-property, but I don't really understand how I should use `bw` to include my given bandwidth!

Comment: Why not `iirnotch(520/8000,100/8000)`?

Comment: Maybe 520/4000 would be better

Comment: yes, I think it would. Recall that relative frequency is taken from the Nyquist frequency rather than the sample rate.

Comment: @Thefoilist You are all right. I managed to filter the given audiofile. However isn't the information on the mathworks-page a bit misleading? I thought i had to calculate the q-factor after reading the page!

Comment: I don't think its misleading, especially when you look at the examples they give. I would agree it isn't exactly obvious though, which is why a lot of people end up using fdatool